# conditional statement in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having difficulty on creating conditional statement in jquery, the original code is shown below:

http://jsfiddle.net/phann/7Qzzg/1/

and i make some modification on the code, like below. But it seems doesn't work. Is there anyone could give me the solution?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//using jquery for click event
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('.image');
    var textStatus = "";
    var timeofclock;
    var randomnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*12); //create random number from 1-12
    $("#randomnumber_value").html(randomnumber);
    if(img.length > 0){
        var offset = img.offset();
        function mouse(evt){
            var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
            var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
            var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
            var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
            var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 


            img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            $("#degree_value").html(degree);

            if(degree>(-61)&&degree<(-55)){
                timeofclock = 1;
            }
            else if(degree>(-33)&&degree<(-25){
                timeofclock = 2;
            }
            else if(degree>(-1)&&degree<(2){
                timeofclock = 3;
            }

            //jika benar maka angka berubah, tampilkan status menang
            if(timeofclock==randomnumber){
                //randomnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*12); //create random number from 1-12
                //$("#randomnumber_value").html(randomnumber);
                textStatus = "CORRECT..!";
                $("#textStatus").html(textStatus);

            }
            else{
                textStatus = "";
                $("#textStatus").html(textStatus);
            }
        }
        $(document).mousedown(mouse);
    }
});
</script>
```

from the editor I used, error is shown in the following line `else if(degree>(-33)&&degree<(-25){`

is there a special way to use conditional statement in jquery?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: How about add some whitespaces to make your code readable ?

Comment: There are no "conditional statement in jquery": javascript is the language, jQuery is only a framework.

Comment: @SLaks from the editor I used, error is shown in the following line `else if(degree>(-33)&&degree<(-25){` then i found the solution by removing the bracket of **-33**  and **-25**. then i try to post Q&A..

Comment: You should also post the error message.

Comment: @moonwave99, thx, I'm still newbie

Comment: @SLaks, i'm using dreamwever cs 6, the error message is _There is a syntax error in line 36. code hinting may not work until you fix this error_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the parentheses.

```
  else if(degree>(-33)&&degree<(-25){ is not correct
  else if(degree>(-33)&&degree<(-25)){ is correct
```

Comment: Note this same problem exists on the next else-if as well.

Comment: @vinothini, gosh i was slipshod. and i got (-2) from this post

Answer (score 0):

it should be done like this

```
if(degree > -61 && degree < -55){
            timeofclock = 1;
        }
        else if(degree > -33 && degree < -25){
            timeofclock = 2;
        }
        else if(degree > -1 && degree < 2){
            timeofclock = 3;
        }
```